# why am I getting status code error while registering user through django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am developing an authentication system for User registration through Django restframework. I have followed [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OhF6FEdIao&t=632s) link to configure serialzers. Since the Tutor is not using class based views, So, I didn't follow that part. I have written own class based view for `ListCreateAPIView`.

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import NewEmployeeProfile


class RegistrationSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    '''
    We need to add the password2, as its not the part of the NewEmployeeProfile model. So, we need to make it manually.
    '''
    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type: password'}, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = NewEmployeeProfile
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'employee_code', 'contact', 'dob', 'password', 'password2')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        """
        before we save the new user, we need to make sure that the password1, and password2 matches. In order to do
        that, we need to override the save() method.
        """
        account = NewEmployeeProfile(
            email=self.validated_data['email'],
            first_name=self.validated_data['first name'],
            last_name=self.validated_data['last name'],
            employee_code=self.validated_data['employee code'],
            contact=self.validated_data['contact'],
            dob=self.validated_data['dob'],
        )

        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']

        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': f'password must match..'})
        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()
        return account
```

### views.py

```
class UserRegisterView(ListCreateAPIView):
    create_queryset = NewEmployeeProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RegistrationSerializers(create_queryset, many=True)
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = RegistrationSerializers(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            newUser = serializer.save()
            serializer = RegistrationSerializers(newUser)
            return Response(data={"status": "OK", "message": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(data={"status": "error"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

NOTE: I am using custom User model

### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('Enter the email before proceeding'))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, password=password, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user


class NewEmployeeProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    employee_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'contact']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.email)
```

### APP.urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import signupView, UserRegisterView


urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', signupView, name='signup'),
    path('register/', UserRegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
    ]
```

### project.urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('/api/accounts/', include('drf_registration.urls')),
    path('apii/', include('AUTHENTICATION.urls')),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

When I test the API in the POSTMAN for POST method, I get below error:

```
{
    "status": "error"
}
```

POSTMAN url: localhost:8000/apii/register/

I have attached a screenshot for reference[image]

curl output

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8000/apii/register/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: csrftoken=rMmU3sp2Z75ijK47MY3ajwmGqr9J0qm3SQu4iDvAf1e54nibybpZMPNQsBoFpDua' \
--form 'email="test.test@yahoo.com"' \
--form 'first name="Ami"' \
--form 'last name="Sah"' \
--form 'employee code="00060"' \
--form 'contact="7507973333"' \
--form 'password="123456"' \
--form 'password2="123456"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some corrections,

1. Move the serializer validation part to the validate method.
2. serializer_class in the view must be a class and not a serializer instance. Change that to serializer_class = RegistrationSerializers.
3. Don't branch serializer.is_valid() with an if, instead change it to serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True) # For debugging. You'll understand what fields have errors. Or you could log serializer.errors after the call to serializer.is_valid().
4. Override ModelSerializer.create instead of ModelSerializer.save. It's more suited for that purpose.
5. I don't understand the point of having a password double-check validation at the backend. Just let the frontend handle it.

Comment: I followed your suggestion, and there are some difference in the output that I see in the POSTMAN. But I still have some discrepancies. For which I will open another thread separately. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: added postman as curl in the original post